# How do I run system executables with aliases within R?

Tags: r, path, system, alias

Suppose, I am running system command in R to run an `executable`.

`inputfile <- "/path/myfile.txt"`

How can I replace `/path/myfile.txt` in the below command with `inputfile` as shown in the command below?

`system ("executable -input inputfile  -output output.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either of these:

```
library(gsubfn)

fn$system("executable -input $inputfile  -output output.txt")
```

or without packages:

```
cmd <- sprintf("executable -input %s -output output.txt", inputfile)
system(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work if I am working with syntax like this: `system ("plink --bfile inputfile  --freq")`. This command automatically generates outputfile.

Comment: The question was *How can I replace /path/myfile.txt in the below command with inputfile as shown in the command below?* and the code shown certainly does do that.  It's not at all clear what the difference is in your second example but if you want to replace inputfile with /path/myfile.txt then it would be done the same way.

Comment: Not necessarily relevant here, but I would suggest (to the OP) that you be defensive with `shQuote` or at least `sQuote` and such. (R's `system` and `system2` are very broken, perhaps the [`sys`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sys/) package is better. Thoughts, G?)