# Using alias in system input in R

Tags: r

I am running an executable called plink using system command. It generates an output file. How can I replace the alias `myinputfile` with inputfile in the command below?

`inputfile <- "myinputfile"`

command:

`system ("plink --bfile inputfile --freq")`

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48895741/3358272) from 25 minutes earlier? It was answered and you accepted it, even, before you asked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try simply pasting together the string you want in system:

```
inputfile <- "myinputfile"
system.string <- paste0("plink --bfile ",inputfile," --freq")
system(system.string)
```

You could also use [`sprintf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10651680/3965651).